# sharepoint 2013: customize tool pane web part in app

Tags: 2013, web-part, sharepoint-addin

The tool pane properties allows only 4 types. Among them, the enum properties would be nice for me if I could get datas from a list. Unfortunately it seems I cannot customize it (seems only datas inside the xml can be set). Does anybody know how to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with this by storing settings in a custom list within your app. Then you can create your own tool pool pane that interacts with this.